# Git Merge Original Repo into Fork

Tags: git, github

I want to manage a few apps for different customers. I want to fork them from a mother project that has all key features every customer needs. I will use the forks to customize the different apps, brand them and sometimes add specific features. 
Now I would like to add some new key features, e.g. Apple Watch support or anything else that is asked for every fork.

So my question is: Is there a way to do add the new features to the mother app and push the changes to the forks? Or do I have to work with branches and push the mother branch into the heirs?

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as library as suggested in another answer. Real git way is this:

- At first setup your master to track to remote original repo master.
- Than pull original master.
- Checkout your custom branch
- make rebase with branch master
- now your custom branch contain new possibility
  from mother project and you can push custom branch to its custom repo

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was looking for the things rebase can do!

Comment: Rebase may need to do merging during rebase process. Each commit where same lines of code changed in both branches you need to fix manually. The rebase process will stop and ask you to fix. It will show instructions how to continue.

Comment: One more comment. it is better to do this in one more separated branch. For cases where some troubles may appear you can get back to not modified custom branch.

Comment: Typically during a rebase, you can just `rebase --abort` if there are problems, so a "saftey net" branch is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks guys, you are great

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you right of course but additional branch may help to solve some problems concerning manual merging errors or typos. It is addition motions and it sometimes may be helpful but generally it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a library with all of the common features between all variations of the app. The library can be in its own repo with separate repos for each variation. This is by far the best solution, in my opinion, since you can make changes to the library independently from the individual apps.

Comment: The rebase feature is the one I was looking for but I also like your idea. I gonna see how I can transform the current project but it's also really good! :)